# Brackets doesn't load my canvas

Tags: javascript, html, reference

When I'm referencing my JavaScript file to my `index.html` file (two separate files in the same folder), and I load the html file in a browser, the drawing i made in the javascript file doesnt show in the canvas.

**Here is this `HTML` code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>snake</title>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="snake.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <canvas id="dots" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
   </body>
</html>
```

**and here is the JavaScript:**

```
function snake() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("dots");
    var snakehead = canvas.getContext('2d');
    snakehead.beginPath();
    snakehead.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    snakehead.stroke();
    snakehead.fillStyle = "#2776ff";
    snakehead.fill();
}
snake();
```

in JS-fiddle the code works, it looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/j2ny6gaf/72/

I'm also getting some errors from JSLint.

"Missing use of 'strict' statement, on the var canvas = document.getElementById
"Combine this with the previous var statement var snake = canvasgetcontext

and a ERROR;
"Document is not defined.[no-undef]

Comment: are both files is in same directory, and also check your files names. because same code is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="snake.js"></script>
```

Inside the head section.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your script inside the head section (script src=“file-name.js” /script) and try adding a canvas size.

Comment: i phrased my question wrong. i can load the canvas actually, but i cant see the drawing i made on the canvas . but i still added your suggestion as you can see now (i edited the post with your suggestions), and i still cant see the snake i made in the js file.

Comment: ok, i got it to work now by putting the javascript in the head section. the problem was that i had the JS in a separate file. im still wondering though, when should i use a different file? if i wanted to have the Javascript for the snake in a separate file instead of coding it into the html file.

Comment: I believe this could help you http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.onload = function snake() {...}
```